# ¿Que puedo hacer para recuperar los elementos de htdocks?

Tags: xampp

accidentalmente elimine la carpeta htdocks y ya desinstale e instale de nuevo el programa pero sigue sin aparecer el contenido de la carpeta ¿que puedo hacer?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ir a la papelera y restaurar los archivos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.